# how to filter object in javascript using filter function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter javascript object using filter function .But I am getting error key is not defined .here is my code 
https://jsfiddle.net/13n8n3om/

```
var arr=[
  {
    "EX": {

      "division": "abc",
      "is_active": true,

    }
  },
 {
    "PY": {

      "division": "pqwww",
      "is_active": false,

    }
  }
];

 arr = arr.filter(function(obj) {
                return obj[key] !== 'EX';
            });

            console.log(arr)
```

**Expected output**

```
[

 {
    "PY": {

      "division": "pqwww",
      "is_active": false,

    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Well thats because you never define `key`

Comment: `obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]` would probably work.

Comment: `obj.hasOwnProperty('EX')` should work. @Andy it may not work if `obj` has more than one properties.

Comment: Yeah, that's preferable. I always forget about that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the key of the object if it is unequal with the given string.

```js
var arr = [{ "EX": { "division": "abc", "is_active": true, } }, { "PY": { "division": "pqwww", "is_active": false, } }];

arr = arr.filter(function (obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj)[0] !== 'EX';
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
return obj[key] !== 'EX';
```

with

```
return Object.keys(obj)[0] !== 'EX';
```

basically you need to access the first property of `obj` and key is undefined.

Comment: @user944513 correct it again... Nina's answer should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the `obj` isn't `EX` like so :

```
arr = arr.filter(function(obj, key) {
          if (! obj.EX) {
              return obj;
          }
       });
```